# The import android.widget.TextView cannot resolve

Tags: java, android

Here's the code:

```
package com.example.sample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView; // (errorL:" the import android.widget.TextView cannot resolve")
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class PlayerActivity extends Activity {
    int count=0;
    TextView // error:"syntax error on token "TextView",delete this tokon)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.player, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend breaking the problem statement out from the code; write the code so that it can be copied, pasted, and compiled, and describe what is going wrong separately.  Also, please tell us *how* you're trying to compile it.  Form the Command Line? From an IDE?  That will help us tell you how to adjust classpaths, project settings, etc.

Comment: Is it an Android project? I guess not and thus has no android.jar in the compile path.

Comment: remove import statement. initialise textview. hover cursor on textview then import.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project > Clean on eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes eclipse does that to you. First of all, try to exit out from eclipse and restart it, it should fix your issue. If it doesn't try Project->clean project. If it still doesn't work, make sure you haven't mess up with R.java file. If you are not sure, simply create new project and copy, Paste your code.

I hope this helps.